# How to override the Yii core functionality?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am new to Yii, actually the problem is, many times i am facing the problem like Non-object error.

It was occurred due to relations. ie for instance, we are having two table called patient and facility, to display the data in admin page we have to map these two tables and display the records there. Now when we delete the facility id for any one of the matching record for patient table non-object error occurred.

I do not know, yii created based on database relations or not, but yii relation works like left join normally, even though as compared to core mysql concept left join gives results exact results like facility table values as null instead of value when they are not matching records.

But in case of yii, this will not create the facility array even empty field names, that is why non object error throws, to resolve these kind of error do we have any solution on yii framework itself?

Otherwise i have one idea to resolve this, have to find the file which building these joins on yii and instead of empty array we can fill the table structure ( ie field name as null or empty value) , then the data will be displayed like empty, so that we can fix these kind of error.

Any one can tell me where have to find that file and where i have to touch the code?

Thanks in advance

Ex:

**I need like this**

```
patient => 
        id=>1
        name=>venkat
        facilityid=> 1
        facility=> array(
                            'id'=>''
                            'facilityname'=>''
                        )
```

**Instead of**

```
patient => 
        id=>1
        name=>venkat
        facilityid=> 1
        facility=> array(

                        )
```

Comment: Have you considered throwing in some logic that simply checks if the value is an empty array? Ex: `if( empty( $patient->facility ) ) { // do something }` ? You shouldn't modify Yii's core.

Comment: yes we can do like this, but one of the best framework does not have the solution in yii itself? or it may be bug i think, this is some what difficult in developer point of view.

Comment: If we have to change the in one place it will be cured rather than checking on every file, if it is ok, let me know the solution.

Comment: @venkat. The solution will not be in the framework, as good as it gets. The framework makes available an object view of the relation as a PHP construct (for example $patient->facility). is that does not exist, any framework cannot invent a value. It is up to you to ensure you are accessing the value correctly. Therefore visevo's comment is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

If the relation does not exist, it returns a null value for HAS ONE and an empty array for HAS MANY types. You should be using this to check if the relation does exist or not, and not just expect it to contain an empty related model or array of empty related models.

If you want to change the behavior of core functionality, then extend any of the core classes, override the necessary methods and use that class instead. In this case, I think you might have to work on the CActiveRecord class, figure out how it calls relations (probably uses the __get() magic method) and rewrite that. I think that's more work than just checking if the relation exists (and you might also potentially screw something else up too in the process).

Answer (score 0):

If you need this functionality, why not just put a class between your model and and ActiveRecord class and override the function to suite your coding style?

no need to change the core